# signature_pad not working in Laravel 5 app

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6, jQuery 3.3.1, bootstrap 3.3.7, and PHP 7.1.4

I'm trying to incorporate a jQuery plugin signature_pad 
https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad to capture a signature.
I haven't even gotten to any code yet for retrieving and storing the signature I'm just trying to draw on the page. I'm trying to include the plugin via the cdn and I'm thinking my app is not recognizing it. I've tried including the cdn in the head tag and also in the body before the closing tag neither makes a difference.

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js'></script>
```

Here is part of my html

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-xs-12'>
      <canvas id='signature-pad' class='signature-pad border_thin'></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

In looking at the code sample https://jsfiddle.net/szimek/jq9cyzuc/ there is no JavaScript needed to enable the signature-pad. I only see the code for utilizing the buttons and such. I did try including the JavaScript in the sample but I get an error that canvas is undefined. So for now I don't have any JavaScript for the signature_pad.

When the page loads I get the signature box but nothing happens when I drag my mouse in the box so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've spent days googling but have not found anything that gets me to the point where I can just draw on the screen. The only thing I've found is to try putting the cdn in the body which I've tried but nothing changed.

I realize I haven't included very much code but I'm not sure what else would be helpful, let me know if anything else is needed.

Thanks for taking the time to read this - any help is appreciated!

Well I finally figured it out, it does have to be initialized. Here is the jQuery, hopefully it helps others out

```
var canvas = $('#signature-pad');
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

signature_pad has to be initialized, here is the code using jQuery

```
var canvas;
var signaturePad;

$('#signature-pad').each(function (index, value) {
    canvas = $('#signature-pad');                   // needed to initialize signature_pad
    signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas[0]);     // needed to initialize signature_pad
    signaturePad.penColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';

    loadCustomerSignature();
});
```